# How can I use the "Roles" parameter when Customising the Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I am using MVC3, C# and Razor.

I am trying to customise the Authorize attribute.

A code snippet:

```
public class AuthorizeCustomAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            return false;
        }

        var user = httpContext.User;
        if (user.IsInRole("Admin")) // This should not be hardcoded, but use the Roles parm somehow. This is the core of my question here.
        {
            return true;
        }
```

The attribute, when used, would look like:

```
[AuthorizeCustom(Roles="Admin,User")]
```

It would be very useful to get access to this "Roles" parameter and its values within the custom attribute class, but I cannot see how to do it. There must be a property in the "httpContext" variable, but it escapes me.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User")]
```

uses a [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664614%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Which is actually a property in the class of the attribute. Since your class derives from `AuthorizeAttribute`, which contains [this property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.roles.aspx):

```
public string Roles { get; set; }
```

You should be able to use it as an argument in the constructor of `AuthorizeCustom`.

Comment: Do I have to test this Roles property specifically or is this occurring in the base class, and therefore is there a result property I can called like RolesValid ? I cannot see anything so I am surmising that I need to do "if IsInRoles(Roles) {return true}"

Comment: I think it is incorporated in "base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext)" automatically?

Comment: Yes it is, just confirmed :)

Comment: Yes, the authorize methods will takes roles into account.